# my code(If statements are returning wrong results

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub redrer()
    Dim s As LongPtr
    Dim k As String
    Dim t As Integer
    Dim r As Long
    Worksheets("sheet3").Activate
    Range("B2").Select

    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
        s = ActiveCell.Value
        k = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
        t = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)
        r = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)

        If Len(k) = 2 And s > 15000 Or s < 35000 Then
            t = 10
        ElseIf Len(k) = 3 And s > 15000 Or s < 35000 Then
            t = 20
        Else
            t = 0
        End If

        If Len(k) = 2 And s > 35000 Or s < 75000 Then
            t = 44
        ElseIf Len(k) = 3 And s > 35000 Or s < 75000 Then
            t = 48
        Else
            t = 0
        End If

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = t
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

he keeps returning t= 44 or 48 even if the s were like between 15000 or 35000
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: If Len(k) = 2 And s > 15000 Or s < 35000 Then will always be true. You probably want If Len(k) = 2 And s > 15000 AND s < 35000 Then

Comment: so i should replace all the or with AND?

Comment: @tehcoder -  I would suggest you don't use `ElseIf` at all, and **especially** don't nest `Else` and `ElseIf`'s together.  Also, I don't understand why you have the two sets of If statements in a row, looking at and setting the same variables.  A proper explanation of what you're trying to do would be helpful - otherwise it's impossible to give you a definite answer.

Comment: can i post imgur link here? like in the comment section?

Comment: okay i have this table in which there's like 5 rows (Name,Salary,Haskids,TaxRate,Tax to pay)
now his tax rate depends on two things :- having kids,and Salary
if he have kids he would have to pay more,is it clear now?

Comment: @tehcoder you can't post images in the comment section, and if you have any examples, codes or images to add, you should do so in an [edit] to the question, so that everything is in one place and easier to understand.

Comment: so i can post imgur link in the post?

Comment: @tehcoder  - Before doing anything else, it would be a good idea to learn how this site works; First, check out the [tour] (where you'll earn a badge!), as well as FAQ's such as "[ask]" and also **"[mcve]"**.  There are also great tips here: [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not use two 'if else' condition because value of t is always replace with second 'if else' condition that mean first 'if else' condition is use less
2. use 'and operator' check code below :

   ```
   If Len(k) = 2 And s > 15000 and s < 35000 Then
       t = 10
   ElseIf Len(k) = 3 And s > 15000 and s < 35000 Then
       t = 20       
   ElseIf Len(k) = 2 And s > 35000 and s < 75000 Then
       t = 44
   ElseIf Len(k) = 3 And s > 35000 and s < 75000 Then
       t = 48
   Else
       t = 0
   End If
   ```

Best of luck :)

Comment: i tried this,but it still gave me alot of 0 results,but better than the one before (he kinda ignored the ones that have "no" in them

Comment: the result is depending on 'k' also if length of 'k' is not equal to 2 or 3 the value always 0 

k is not mandatory the use
Dim s 
    Dim k
    Dim t 
    Dim r
    s = 20000

        If Len(k) = 2 or s > 15000 and s < 35000 Then
            t = 10

I implemented that code it will work

Comment: yes but the length of k its always either 2 or 3